# (Python) Searching for a exact string in .txt and returning result

Tags: python, string, search, logging, text

I'm trying to write a Python program that prompts the user to enter a string and then open up a text file, search the file for the exact match and then return the details that are related to that string.

The string that is returned gets stored to a variable and then writes to a separate new .txt file. (I'm basically creating a logfile that logs all of my ham radio contacts).

The problem I'm running into is that it returns everything in the string instead of just a exact match. (EX- if user enters K8YP, it will return K8YPA, K8YPB, K8YPC etc instead of just K8YP).

Here is an example of how the text file is structured:

```
EN|215000|||AA0A|L|L00209566|MC CARTHY, DENNIS J|DENNIS|J|MC CARTHY|||||5022 LANSDOWNE AVE|SAINT LOUIS|MO|63109|||000|0002274249|I|||^M
EN|215001|||AA0AA|L|L00196154|MONKS, WILLIAM S|WILLIAM|S|MONKS|||||W 529 Nebraska Hall, UN-L|Lincoln|NE|685880514||c/o Scott L. Gardner, HWML|000|0002268431|I|||^M
EN|215002|||AA0AB|L|L00185374|CROM SR, RAYMOND L|RAYMOND|L|CROM|SR||||12291 BRIGHTON RD|HENDERSON|CO|80640|33||000|0002144756|I|||^M
EN|215003|||AA0AC|L||PETH, ESTHER T|ESTHER|T|PETH|||||BENEDICTINE CONVENT|CLYDE|MO|64432|||000||I|||^M
EN|215004|||AA0AD|L|L00310459|Odermann, William|William||Odermann|||||804 Second Street NW|New Prague|MN|56071|||000|0004694238|I|||^M
```

My current code is listed below...

```
#This program will log amateur radio contacts and store them in a database.

import time
import sys

def main():
    countdown =3
    print ("\n")
    print "Starting in"

    for countdown in range (3, 0, -1):
        print countdown
        time.sleep(0.25)
    print ("\n")    
    #Asking user for callsign input data
    callsign = raw_input('Please enter the callsign: ')
    print ("\n")

    #Asking user for frequency input data
    frequency = raw_input('Please enter the frequency in MHz: ')
    print ("\n")

    #Asking user to review and confirm the entry
    print ('Callsign: ' + callsign)
    print('Frequency: ' + frequency)
    print ("\n")

    request = raw_input('Enter 1 to confirm and 0 to cancel: ')
    print ("\n")

    #Commands for grabbing date and time
    date_time_stamp = time.strftime("%c")

    if request == '1':
        with open('EN.dat', 'r') as searchfile:
            for line in searchfile:
                if callsign in line:
                    text_file = open("Contact_Logs.txt", "a")
                    text_file.write("Callsign: %s\n" % callsign)
                    text_file.write("Frequency: %s\n" % frequency)
                    text_file.write("Date/Time: %s\n" % date_time_stamp)
                    text_file.write("%s\n" % line)
                    text_file.close
                    print line
                    print("The contact was logged successfully!")
                    print ("\n")

    else:
        print "Log request was cancelled!"
        print ("\n")

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help fixing my problem is greatly appreciated. :)

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example provided, you should search for `"|"+callsign+"|"` to avoid false positives: `if ("|"+callsign+"|") in line:`. This assumes there can be no space between "|" and the callsign, etc.

The approach based on regular expressions would be more robust, but more work is needed.